# Spark jobs are not running on emr

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, amazon-emr, hue

I am getting this message recently when I submit a spark job to emr amazon:

> there is no Node Manager or Container available

what I should do to solve this error?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. can you add more information about the issue? Thanks.

Comment: the same error in the following link but under emr not cloudera: 
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/The-application-might-not-be-running-yet-or-there-is-no-Node/td-p/48106